# %attr in rpm.spec does not take env variable's value

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a rpm.spec file in which i have to give file permissions for a file.

I want %attr to take $user and $group values during the rpm installation.(where i will be doing "export user=" and "export group=")
but it does not take these values,instead gives a syntax error while installing the rpm.

I have something like this in my specfile

```
%pre

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
<some_path>
%config /etc/akshatha
%doc /usr/share/doc/akshatha
%attr(0700,$user,$group) %dir directory_path
%attr(0700,$user,$group) %dir directory_path
%attr(0600,$user,$group) path_to_file
```

this gives me an error, while installing the rpm as -

```
warning: user $user does not exist - using root
warning: group $group does not exist - using root
```

I have even tried giving %attr(0700,%{getenv:user},%{getenv:group}) but this fails while preparing the rpm itself saying

```
RPM build errors:
Bad syntax: %attr(0700)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. `%attr` is fixed at build time; you specifically asked for "during the rpm installation" which won't work.

In your `%post` you can `chown` but then that will break your verification.

Comment: it will break the verfication in what sense ?

Comment: `rpm -V` will report that the mode of the file differ compared to what rpmdb think it should be.

Comment: chmod: cannot access ‘<path_to_dir>’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘<path_to_dir>’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As @AaronD.Marasco said: this is not possible **during rpm installation**. If you want to define it **during build**; then you can proceed like this:

you can define macros on the command line when invoking `rpmbuild`:

in the spec file:

```
%attr(0700,%{file_user},%{file_group}) /path/to/file
```

invoke `rpmbuild` like this:

```
rpmbuild --define='file_user some_user' --define='file_group some_group'
```

Comment: OP said "during the rpm installation" which isn't possible.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco you are correct; I corrected my answer and you have my upvote :)

Comment: @AkshathaRamesh if your question is answered, then please consider accepting any of these answers to mark your question as solved. You can optionally upvote other usefull answers.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, it is not possible this way. Considering what you are trying to achieve, I would do it this way:

```
%pre
getent group GROUPNAME >/dev/null || groupadd -r GROUPNAME

%files
%config /etc/akshatha
%doc /usr/share/doc/akshatha
%attr(0770,root, GROUPNAME) %dir directory_path
...
```

and then I would instruct admin to put the user into group GROUPNAME.

Comment: yes, i am doing the same way.. but the thing is group and user will be given my users in runtime(in sense while installing the rpm) . So, getent group $GROUPNAME >/dev/null || groupadd -r $GROUPNAME . what ever evn is set for $GROUPNAME by the user should be taken .. the same thing should be applied for %attr(0770,root, $GROUPNAME) %dir directory_path