# Is there a way to build an rpm with user configurable users as part of useradd and attr in rpm spec?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a user and a usergroup created as part of my rpm spec with a hardcoded user. I want to make this user configurable. Also, the `%files` has a `%attr` that uses the same user and sets permissions on a few dir. 
Is there a way to make this possible? So, my expectation is that the rpm, when installed should have this user defined user and user group created with the permissions set to the dir as this user.

```
#%files
#%defattr(-,root,root,-)

#/usr/bin/*
#%attr(0700,user1,user1) %dir <dir>

%pre 
/usr/bin/getent group user1 >/dev/null || /usr/sbin/groupadd -r user1
if ! /usr/bin/getent passwd user1 >/dev/null ; then 
    sudo /usr/sbin/useradd -r -d %{_prefix}/user1-g user1-s /sbin/nologin  || echo "Unexpected error adding user \"user1\",Aborting installation."
fi
```

I want to have a configurable user instead of user1.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [%attr in rpm.spec does not take env variable's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233258/attr-in-rpm-spec-does-not-take-env-variables-value)

Comment: this is strangely similar to the other question. Do you have the same school assignment?

Comment: nope, we work for the same team at work and were trying to get around this issue. Both of us unaware that the other raised an issue here :)